# What needs to be added to path "@/lib/utils" when tryinng to use ``shadcn/ui`` components?

Tags: reactjs, shadcnui

I am trying to use `shadcn` dropdown component in my react application. I am not using Tailwind. I followed their doc and chose the path to add the code manually, but now I get an error as

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@/lib/utils'
  3 | import { CheckIcon, ChevronRightIcon, DotFilledIcon } from "@radix-ui/react-icons";
  4 |
> 5 | import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
  6 |
  7 | const DropdownMenu = DropdownMenuPrimitive.Root;
```

Please guide me on what needs to be added to folder `@/lib/utils`

Answer (score 0):

`@/` is an alias path that must be defined in your `tsconfig.json` or its equivalent.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
    }
  },
}
```

The path specified between `[]` should be relative to your `lib` folder. If your `lib` is within the `src` directory, it should be `["./src/*"]`. If your `lib` is at the root, it should be `["./*"]`.